# How to hide the parent element without $this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide the parent().parent() of an element on onclick.But there is already a click function defined on that element(for other programmatic purpose).I don't know how to get $(this) on that function.I know to do these only with $(this).Also I don't know is it allowed to write two click function for same element.I think  its good if it all happens in one function.

Here is my HTML

```
<tr>
<td>116</td>
<td class="name"><a href=""><span></span></a></td>
td>03.11.2013 13:26</td>
<td></td>
<td class="ed">
 <a href="#" onclick="removeLinkID(116);">Remove<span class="green"></span></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

My jquery function is :

```
function removeLinkID(item) {

if(Links=='item_link_2'){


    var Id = item;  
    if (IdsBanner== '') {
     IdsBanner.splice(0, IdsBanner.length);
     console.log('s'); 
     }
    IdsBanner.push(Id);
    console.log(IdsBanner);
    return IdsBanner;
}
```

I need to hide the tr on the click of a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `id` to the `TR` element and then hide it.

**HTML:**

```
<tr id="item-116">
```

**JS:**

```
function removeLinkID(item) {
  $('#item-' + item).hide();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Florent, he needs to hide it, not remove it.
 $('#item-' + item).css('display', 'none');

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="ed">
 <a href="#" onclick="removeLinkID(116,this);">Remove<span class="green"></span></a>
</td>

function removeLinkID(item,el) {
   $(el).parent("tr").hide();
}
```